# Warning from IE when testing my OCX

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I have a signed OCX on my local PC. when the script loads it IE outputs a warning box: 
"An ActiveX control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want to allow this interaction?"

Is there's a way to remove this warning?
10xs,
Nir